# Tensorflow js in react native very slow

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

I am trying to serve a deep learning model from mobiles. My react native app using tensorflow takes about a minute just to load. My model is about 175mb (about 30 million params). This is my first time trying to run a model on mobiles and I couldn't find any good performance data for tensorflow js on react native.

Is my model too large to expect a reasonably quick loading and inference time on react native? Is this because of hardware limitation or framework? I read that tfjs react native uses web-gl which would be slower than direct access the mobile's gpu so could I use core ml or something like that and expect a better time?

As an extra question (I'll also make a separate post), another route I'm considering is moving inference to a web browser for laptops/desktops. Could I expect a browser web-gl to perform as well as directly using the computer gpu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you ML Kit and Core ML are much faster than TF.js.
Also you can create your model, convert it to TF lite then deploy it to firebase and use your model on ios and android in the native side, (currently [@react-native-firebase/ml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/ml). does not support custom models).